# Set-ADUser via UNIX Python

Tags: powershell, unix

We're looking at some automation where if X event happens, then it will call a PowerShell script to perform a few actions. The issue is that our platform is UNIX and I'm having mixed results running PowerShell commands.

I've installed the PowerShell RPM on CentOS 7 and I have it working for basic commands such as "Invoke-Command -computername" and pull down netstat information or something like that. My issue is the specific Active Directory modules for UNIX.

Below is the code I want to run but I get a "Set-ADUser is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program".

How can I import this module into CentOS so I can then run the commands below?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import os
import getpass

userid = input('Enter the username you want to force a password reset on: ')
username = input('Enter your domain username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Enter your domain password: ')

os.system("pwsh -c '$username = \"" + username + "\"; $password = \"" + password + "\";  \
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String \"" + password + "\" -AsPlainText -Force; $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$userpassword; \
Set-ADUser " + userid + "-ChangePasswordAtLogon $true'")
```

I see https://pypi.org/project/pyad/ as a potential module for this but still not seeing the Set-ADUser command referenced and also not the ChangePasswordAtLogon option.

Note: I know some of the sending password information isn't great right now, just doing a quick test to see if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and from what I can tell, Microsoft isn't supporting the AD modules within UNIX. Therefore I had to rely on invoking the command on a Windows computer.

I'm still open for other suggestions but this is technically working now.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName domain_controller -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {Set-ADUser " + user + " -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true}
```